# What is causing DiscordAPIError[30034] when trying to deploy 6 commands to a Discord bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js

When i added a new /poll command, i started getting this error whenever i tried restarting my discord bot :

```
> node deploy-commands.js && node stolas_bot.js

Started refreshing 6 application (/) commands.
DiscordAPIError[30034]: Max number of daily application command creates has been reached (200)
    at handleErrors (/home/Eth22/delivery/Discord Bot/stolas_bot_js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:640:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (/home/Eth22/delivery/Discord Bot/stolas_bot_js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1021:23)
    at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (/home/Eth22/delivery/Discord Bot/stolas_bot_js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:862:14)
    at async REST.request (/home/Eth22/delivery/Discord Bot/stolas_bot_js/node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:1387:22)
    at async /home/Eth22/delivery/Discord Bot/stolas_bot_js/deploy-commands.js:36:16 {
  requestBody: {
    files: undefined,
    json: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]
  },
  rawError: {
    message: 'Max number of daily application command creates has been reached (200)',
    code: 30034
  },
  code: 30034,
  status: 400,
  method: 'PUT',
  url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/[token]/commands'
}
```

I've seen people talking about a 200 command limit, but i am nowhere close to it
So what can i do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error on discords side.
See [Github](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/6188)

Should be fixed soon

Comment: Oh i see, i didnt came across this post while searching thats my bad.